# Chrome doesn't trust my self-signed SSL certicate

Tags: google-chrome, security, ssl, self-signed

I've already imported my self-signed SSL certificate into the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" in Google chrome, (restarted chrome as well), but it still shows me this:

[image]

That solution is found in most stackoverflow forums and other websites. Are there any other solutions to make Chrome accept my certificate?

Comment: It's only going to disappear if you have cert from a trusted authority. Its still a working https connection even though it shows a warning.